# Cascading in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cascade

Is there any way to cascade non-key attributes(not a primary key nor a foreign key) with the help of SQL? Is this possible?

Comment: You could use triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use database triggers to maintain the same attribute across multiple tables. But why would you want to cascade a non-key attribute in a relational database?

If you need an attribute in multiple tables, then you should normalise your data structure and create a separate table for the attribute and use foreign keys to reference it. This way you only need to maintain the attribute at on place, yet all changes will be cascaded through the foreign keys.